# Odd C++ template behaviour with static member vars

Tags: c++, templates, static, metaprogramming

This piece of code is supposed to calculate an approximation to *e* (i.e. the mathematical constant ~ 2.71828183) at compile-time, using the following approach;

```
e1 = 2 / 1
e2 = (2 * 2 + 1) / (2 * 1) = 5 / 2   = 2.5
e3 = (3 * 5 + 1) / (3 * 2) = 16 / 6  ~ 2.67
e4 = (4 * 16 + 1) / (4 * 6) = 65 / 24 ~ 2.708
...
e(i) = (e(i-1).numer * i + 1) / (e(i-1).denom * i)
```

The computation is returned via the `result` static member however, after 2 iterations it yields zero instead of the expected value. I've added a static member function f() to compute the same value and that doesn't exhibit the same problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// Recursive case.

template<int Iters, int Num = 2, int Den = 1, int I = 2>
struct CalcE
{
    static const double result;
    static double f () {return CalcE<Iters, Num * I + 1, Den * I, I + 1>::f ();}
};

template<int Iters, int Num, int Den, int I>
const double CalcE<Iters, Num, Den, I>::result = CalcE<Iters, Num * I + 1, Den * I, I + 1>::result;

// Base case.

template<int Iters, int Num, int Den>
struct CalcE<Iters, Num, Den, Iters>
{
    static const double result;
    static double f () {return result;}
};

template<int Iters, int Num, int Den>
const double CalcE<Iters, Num, Den, Iters>::result = static_cast<double>(Num) / Den;
// Test it.

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision (8);

    std::cout << "e2 ~ " <<  CalcE<2>::result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e3 ~ " <<  CalcE<3>::result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e4 ~ " <<  CalcE<4>::result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e5 ~ " <<  CalcE<5>::result << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e2 ~ " <<  CalcE<2>::f () << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e3 ~ " <<  CalcE<3>::f () << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e4 ~ " <<  CalcE<4>::f () << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e5 ~ " <<  CalcE<5>::f () << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tested this with VS 2008 and VS 2010, and get the same results in each case:

```
e2 ~ 2
e3 ~ 2.5
e4 ~ 0
e5 ~ 0

e2 ~ 2
e3 ~ 2.5
e4 ~ 2.6666667
e5 ~ 2.7083333
```

Why does `result` not yield the expected values whereas `f()` does?

According to [Rotsor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166235/rotsor)'s comment below, this does work with GCC, so I guess the question is, am i relying on some type of undefined behaviour with regards to static initialisation order, or is this a bug with Visual Studio?

Comment: Your code [works fine](http://codepad.org/TqziZEMi) if compiled with GNU compiler.

Comment: @Rotsor: thanks, that's useful to know. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't make identifiers all caps, it makes them look like macros. I can't even begin to identify your code.

Comment: I much prefer template parameters in caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't depend on the order of static member initialization, at least in VC++.

Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<int N>
struct one
{
    static const int res;
};

template<>
struct one<0>
{
    static const int res;
};

template<int N>
const int one<N>::res = one<N-1>::res;

const int one<0>::res = 1;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", one<3>::res);
    printf("%d\n", one<2>::res);
    printf("%d\n", one<1>::res);
    printf("%d\n", one<0>::res);
}
```

In VC++ 2008, it produces:

```
0
1
1
1
```

In [codepad](http://codepad.org/dJPax6IG), it produces:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Is the order unspecified in the language? I.e. are both implementations allowed?

Comment: I think the order is unspecified.

Comment: Yes, the order is unspecified. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819131/c-static-member-initalization-template-fun-inside/1825872#1825872)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, results with g++ 4.4.1:

```
e2 ~ 2
e3 ~ 2.5
e4 ~ 2.6666667
e5 ~ 2.7083333

e2 ~ 2
e3 ~ 2.5
e4 ~ 2.6666667
e5 ~ 2.7083333
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't like non-integral compile time constants. A possible solution is to use rational arithmetic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<int Iters, int Num = 2, int Den = 1, int I = 2>
struct CalcE
{
    typedef CalcE<Iters, Num * I + 1, Den * I, I + 1> res;
    enum { num = res::num, den = res::den };
    static double g() { return static_cast<double>(num) / den; }
};

template<int Iters, int Num, int Den>
struct CalcE<Iters, Num, Den, Iters>
{
    enum { num = Num, den = Den };
    static double g() { return static_cast<double>(num) / den; }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision (8);

    std::cout << "e2 ~ " <<  CalcE<2>::g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e3 ~ " <<  CalcE<3>::g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e4 ~ " <<  CalcE<4>::g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e5 ~ " <<  CalcE<5>::g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e5 ~ " <<  CalcE<6>::g() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using non-integral compile time constants was kind of the point, otherwise I can just use my f() function.

Comment: But you can't be sure that f() will indeed be inlined and computed at compile time.