# templated class, nontemplate member: does the member need explicit instantiation in one translation unit to be seen in another w/ a fwd declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This question comes from a CUDA context, where you have multiple compilers in use so bear with me - it presents the situation (otherwise you might ask why this problem would come up or suggest things that would be wastes of time).  Just about every C++ 03 or 11 rule applies depending on the compile flags, I believe there are a few exceptions but let's pretend there are none as this contrived setup could be replicated without `nvcc`.

dvector.h:

```
//parsable by both nvidia's cuda compiler (nvcc) and good old gcc and kin.
//gcc compiled code is expected to link up and call subroutines compiled with cuda for gpu accceleration    
template<typename T>
struct dvector{// a vector for manipulating GPU memory
    size length;
    T *data;
    void fill(const T &val);

};

#if __CUDACC__ //if being parsed by nvidia' compiler
template<typename T>
void dvector<T>::fill(const T &val){
   //do some nvcc-only stuff, gcc wouldn't understand
}
#endif
```

Suppose we have 2 object files we are compiling, both include the header containing this declaration and conditionally defined definition.

- srcfile.cpp is compiled with gcc
- srcfile.cu is compiled with nvcc
- srcfile.h usable with both nvcc and gcc

srcfile.h:

```
#include "dvector.h"
void call_work_kernel(dvector<int> &v);
```

srcfile.cu:

```
#include "srcfile.h"

template<typename T>
__global__ void work_kernel(device_vector<T> v){//purposely by value... this this is the way to pass it
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    if(tid < threadIdx){
        v.data[tid] += 1;
    }
}

void call_work_kernel(dvector<int> &v){
     const size_t blocksize = 32;
     const size_t n_blocks = (v.length + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;
     dim3 blockDims(n_blocks);
     dim3 blockSize(blocksize);
     work_kernel<<<blockDims, blockSize>>>(v);

}
```

srcfile.cpp:

```
int main(){
    device_vector<int>::fill(42);
    call_work_kernel(v);
}
```

So playing by the standard, will the implicit instantiation of `dvector<int>` instantiate member function `dvector<int>::fill`?
Does this still happen with the `dvector<int>&` vs a routine taking `dvector<int>`?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347671/static-member-of-template-class-not-instantiated-unless-explicitly-specialized) quotes what looks to be a draft standard, although I don't have a copy so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: FYI [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81656)

Comment: Obviously, the instantiation can't be done by `gcc`, because it never has the definition of `dvector::fil()` visible. To be clear, the implicit instantiation you're referring to is `dvector<int>` as named in the prototype of `call_work_kernel` which is seen by `nvcc` in a context in which the definition of `dvector::fill()` is visible. And you want to know if the standard says nvcc *must* instantiate this member, *may* instantiate it, or *must not*?

Comment: @Novelocrat not as the named prototype but in trivial usage (accessing the data member, maybe calling other non-fill functions, had they existed) in the call_work_kernel definition . I want to know if this minimal usage and a standards compliant compiler would be required to instantiate this member.

Comment: Could you please edit to show examples of sort of accesses/calls in the definition of `call_work_kernel` you have in mind?

Comment: @novelocrat ok I've introduced more cuda into it to get you a typical example, basically assume fill is not going to be explicitly instantiated or called in the cu file.