# How to force a static member to be initialized?

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, static-initialization

Consider this example code:

```
template<class D>
char register_(){
    return D::get_dummy(); // static function
}

template<class D>
struct Foo{
    static char const dummy;
};

template<class D>
char const Foo<D>::dummy = register_<D>();

struct Bar
    : Foo<Bar>
{
    static char const get_dummy() { return 42; }
};
```

([Also on Ideone](http://ideone.com/YuiG6).)

I'd expect `dummy` to get initialized as soon as there is a concrete instantiation of `Foo`, which I have with `Bar`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819131/c-static-member-initalization-template-fun-inside) (and the standard quote at the end) explained pretty clear, why that's not happening.

> [...] in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

Is there any way to *force* `dummy` to be initialized (effectively calling `register_`) *without* any instance of `Bar` or `Foo` (no instances, so no constructor trickery) and without the user of `Foo` needing to explicitly state the member in some way? Extra cookies for not needing the derived class to do anything.

---

**Edit**: [Found a way](http://ideone.com/pTI77) with minimal impact on the derived class:

```
struct Bar
    : Foo<Bar>
{   //                              vvvvvvvvvvvv
    static char const get_dummy() { (void)dummy; return 42; }
};
```

Though, I'd still like the derived class not having to do that. :|

Comment: We generally don't want the compiler to initialize all unused variables in all class templates. How should the compiler know that **in this case** you want it to? By actually using it?

Comment: @Bo: Sure, but I'd like to hide that use from the derived class / outer world and would rather somehow get that into `Foo` itself. :/

Comment: @Xeo: `static char const get_dummy() { (void)dummy; return 42; }` - I doubt that this circular dependency between `Bar::get_dummy()` and `Foo<Bar>::dummy` is guaranteed to work (by the standard). Looks like highly implementation-dependent trick. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Serge: Why shouldn't it? The `dummy` in `get_dummy` is the uninitialized one, sure, but that doesn't matter. :) I don't actually use it anyways.

Comment: @Xeo: "The dummy in get_dummy is the uninitialized one, sure, but that doesn't matter. :) I don't actually use it anyways." Yea. But why it is supposed to force `Foo<Bar>::dummy` to become initialized? And what is supposed to prevent compiler from optimizing statement `(void)dummy;` (that has no effect) out.

Comment: @Serge: It forces `dummy` to become initialized, because it is *used*, as quoted. w.r.t. optimizations, I'll have to check that.

Comment: @Xeo: "It forces dummy to become initialized, because it is used" Not actually. It is used only if you call `get_dummy()` somewhere. Static members and global variables are initialized either before first statement of `main` or before first using of any object or function defined in the same translation unit as that static member or global variable. So it is totally allowed to not initialize Foo<Bar>::dummy at all if you don't use any objects or functions from the same translation unit where template Foo specialization is instantiated.

Comment: @Serge: No, it counts as "used" just because it is there as a statement. That alone is enough to cause the compiler to initialize it, at least on every compiler I tested this on (MSVC & GCC. :P)

Comment: @Xeo: <<No, it counts as "used" just because it is there as a statement.>> What makes you think so? Any references to the standard? Read the chapter 12.6 ISO/IEC 14882-2003. What your tests show is exactly what implementation-dependent mean. Besides you don't really know what was the exact moment and reason of dynamic initialization of `Foo<Bar>::dummy`. May be `struct Bar: Foo<Bar> {...}` definition alone is enough (that will lead to Foo<Bar> specialization instantiation).

Comment: @Serge: No, the definition alone is not enough. Take out the `(void)dummy` and you won't see the call: http://ideone.com/Kukds

Comment: @Xeo: "Take out the (void)dummy and you won't see the call" I confirm that behavior. But still it is implementation dependent. Standard does not require `dummy` to be initialized even if you add `(void)dummy` to `Bar::get_dummy()`. The result for any particular implementation is not an argument at all. C++ standard statements are.

Comment: Title should read *instantiated*, not *initialized*... those terms are often incorrectly interchanged

Comment: that trick requires to have somwhere call `get_dummy` at least once?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider:

```
template<typename T, T> struct value { };

template<typename T>
struct HasStatics {
  static int a; // we force this to be initialized
  typedef value<int&, a> value_user;
};

template<typename T>
int HasStatics<T>::a = /* whatever side-effect you want */ 0;
```

It's also possible without introducing any member:

```
template<typename T, T> struct var { enum { value }; };
typedef char user;

template<typename T>
struct HasStatics {
  static int a; // we force this to be initialized
  static int b; // and this

  // hope you like the syntax!
  user :var<int&, a>::value,
       :var<int&, b>::value;
};

template<typename T>
int HasStatics<T>::a = /* whatever side-effect you want */ 0;

template<typename T>
int HasStatics<T>::b = /* whatever side-effect you want */ 0;
```

Comment: The first one seems to work [on GCC](http://ideone.com/4t1mi), but is no good in MSVC10, no initialization happens. :/ The second one works on [neither GCC](http://ideone.com/s85LF) nor MSVC10. :( **Edit**: Oh wait, with C++0x enabled [it works on GCC](http://ideone.com/s85LF). Still no luck with MSVC...

Comment: @Xeo it works for me without c++0x on gcc4.6. Don't have any other compiler to try, except clang. On clang the second one doesn't work either. PR is on the way.

Comment: Oh Gosh! what `user :var<int&, a>::value` does mean?

Comment: @pure: It's an unnamed bitfield, effectively a `char : 0;`

Answer (score 5):

We can use a simple trick based on a declaration that must be instantiated with the class:

```
template<…>
struct Auto {
  static Foo foo;
  static_assert(&foo);
};
template<…> Foo Auto::foo=…;
```

Note that some compilers warn about the comparison to null; that can be avoided with `&foo==&foo`, `(bool)&foo`, or `((void)&foo,true)` if needed.

Note also that GCC 9.0–9.2 [don’t count this as an odr-use](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92062).

Comment: The most elegant option so far, thanks. I am a little worried I am calling this "elegant", but hey, this is C++ :)

Comment: Thank, but doesn't work on Visual C++ 2019.  Sound like Visual C++ bug.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that comes to my mind:

```
// in some c++ file (to make i with internal linkage)
static int i = init_dummy(Foo<int>::dummy);
```

where init_dummy is defined like this:

```
int init_dummy(...)
{
  return 1;
}
```

Due to variable args you can put more initializations there like:

```
static int i = init_dummy(Foo<int>::dummy, Foo<double>::dummy, Foo<whatever>::dummy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently bumped into this. The official solution would be explicit template instantiation, described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

In the above case, the statement should look like this:

```
template class Foo::Bar;
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any way to force dummy to be initialized (effectively calling register_) without any instance of Bar or Foo (no instances, so no constructor trickery)?

Wouldn't this be sufficient?

```
std::cout << Foo<int>::dummy;
```

Comment: I hope there are other ways than having the user to explicitly state the member. :|