# Force template static member instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, static, instantiation

I'm trying to create the program that executes some code only if the template is instantiated (it will be used for low-level driver initialization).
Now I have the following solution.

```
class Initializer
{
public:
    Initializer(){
        // This code is executed once
    }

    void silly() const{

    }
};

template <class T>
class Proxy{
protected:
    static const Initializer init;
};

template<class T>
const Initializer Proxy<T>::init;

template<class T>
class MyTemplate : public Proxy<void>{
public:
    static void myMethod1(){
        init.silly();

        // ... Something useful
    }

    static void myMethod2(){
        init.silly();

        // ... Something useful
    }
};
```

The `Initializer` default constructor is executed only in case I call `myMethod1()` or `myMethod2()` somewhere.

But is there a way to get rid of those `init.silly();` lines?

Comment: "Force instantiation:" and "check instantiation" are two rather different things.

Comment: Do you want `Initializer` to be created for each instantiation of `Proxy`? E.g. if you create `Proxy<void>` and `Proxy<char>` then `Initializer` will be constructed twice?

Comment: No, I want only one instance of `Initializer` to be created. I will always inherit from `Proxy<void>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, is that members of a template are not instantiated unless they are referenced.

Rather than calling `init.silly()`, you can just reference the member:

```
    static void myMethod1(){
        (void)init;

        // ... Something useful
    }
```

Or, if you want `init` to be defined absolutely always, you can explicitly instantiate it:

```
template<>
const Initializer Proxy<void>::init{};
```

Comment: It's better but still requires one extra line of code.


If I use the explicit instantiation of `init` its constructor will be executed even if `MyTemplate` is not instantiated. It's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

template and low-level driver initialization?.. I'd try to make it as C as possible :) to ensure exact behavior.

You can do something like this perhaps:

```
class Initializer
{
public:
    Initializer() {
        // This code is executed once
    }
};

template <class T>
class Proxy {
protected:
    Proxy()
    {
        static Initializer init;
    }
};

template<class T>
class MyTemplate : public Proxy<void> {
public:
    void myMethod1() {
        // ... Something useful
    }

    void myMethod2() {
        // ... Something useful
    }
};
```

All your code uses only static functions and doesn't really show why you would use classes and templates. With my change I made `myMethod1` and `myMethod2` non static and Proxy() constructor would create `Initializer` once.

Note that because of all that template mess your `Initializer` might be executed as many times as you instantiate Proxy template. Did you really mean it? If not, convert to clear readable code that doesn't have this unexpected results. This will also be better maintainable and readable for others:

```
class Initializer
{
    Initializer() {
        // This code is executed once
    }
public:
    void init()
    {
        static Initializer init;
    }
};


template<class T>
class MyTemplate {
public:
    static void myMethod1() {
        Initializer::init();
        // ... Something useful
    }

    static void myMethod2() {
        Initializer::init();
        // ... Something useful
    }
};
```

This makes it absolutely clear that `Initializer` will be created only once just before `myMethod1` or `myMethod2` is called. If nothing calls your `Initializer::init` then that code from `Initializer` should be removed at link time.

Comment: Oh yes!  That's much cleaner.  It also saves having to worry about detailed questions about when a template member gets instantiated - which is just the sort of dark corner of the standard that a) developers get confused about; b) *compiler* developers occasionally get confused about.