# CRTP pattern doesn't trigger full template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp

I've created a template class which triggers a runtime text output whenever an instantiation of it occurs:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct verbose {
    verbose()
    {
        std::cout << "Instantation occured!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct base
{
    inline static verbose<T> v;
};
```

When I force to create instantiation, it shows an output:

```cpp
template struct base<int>;
//output: Instantation occured!
```

([Check on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sqqH5R6kBeGfix2M)).

On the other hand, when I use it with a CRTP pattern, it seems that instantiation does not occur:

```cpp
class test : public base<test>
{
};
```

([Check on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vGJTBZJK9bRE55yC))

Is this behavior OK with the ISO standard? Can I somehow force to make instantiation, without requiring users of my template class (`base`) to write additional code? For me, the important thing is the side effect of the static variable constructor.

Comment: When you say "an instantiation", do you mean a template instantiation or creating an instance of an object? Because the code you've written does the latter, not the former. There's no way to get a message during template instantiation, because that's a compile-time process, not a runtime one.

Comment: can't you get a message with static assert

Comment: @NicolBolas The intent is to get the message during program initialization, which works when explicitly instantiating the `base<int>` but not when doing CRTP. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/yp5bGnsCTDcHMtrY.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean exactly template instantiation. Of course, it's a compile-time process, but it can trigger runtime code execution, as it does in the first example from Wandbox.

Comment: @Yamahari Not in a valid program. If you see a message from `static_assert`, your program is ill-formed.

Comment: Odr use `v` (in destructor or constructor for example).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That is incorrect: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6A48EmnnfU0S9kXQ

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Of course it's initialized in runtime, as cout always runs in runtime. The essential part of the question is: "without requiring users of my template class (base) to write additional code" (eg. making an object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)

Answer (score 4):

Your CRTP usage falls under implicit instantiation:

> When code refers to a template in context that requires a completely defined type, or when the completeness of the type affects the code, and this particular type has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs. For example, when an object of this type is constructed, but not when a pointer to this type is constructed.
>
> This applies to the members of the class template: unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated, and does not require a definition.
> <sub>[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)</sub>

Following the second paragraph, since `base<test>::v` is never actually used, no instantiation of `base<test>::v` actually occurs.

Since a usage is required to generate its instantiation, there will need to be additional code to get your desired output. For example, you could add a constructor to `base`:

```
template<typename T>
struct base
{
    inline static verbose<T> v;
    base() { (void)&v; }
};
```

This alone is not enough to trigger your output based on the definition of `test` by itself. However, if your program tries to create an object from `test`, then the formation of the constructor will cause the template's constructor to be used, and thus `base<test>::v` will be instantiated.

Comment: So, from your answer I assume I must require "users of my template class (base) to write additional code". Or just find another way how to allow my class users to be lazy ;)

Comment: If your class users actually try to create an object from `test`, then you can add something to `base<>` to get your output. Answer is updated.