# How can I enforce Static Functions in a class template and reference them

Tags: c++, templates

This is kind of a two-part question, but I believe they're very closely related.

Question 1:

I've read on other questions that there are ways to enforce a class in having certain static functions, like such:

```cpp
class Type{
   virtual void staticVirtual() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class StaticContract{
   void staticVirtual(){
       T::foo();
   }
};
```

If I made a class that inherited from this contract:

```cpp
class Example : public StaticContract<Example>{
   ...
};
```

Then `Example` would have to implement a static function `foo()`.

The problem I'm having is if I make a templated class that inherits from the contract:

```cpp
template <Typename T>
class mTemplateClass : 
   public StaticContract<mTemplateClass<T>>{
   ...
}
```

I don't get any errors for not implementing `foo()`.

How can I enforce a template to have certain static functions that I can call, or is that even possible?

---

Question 2:

Considering the above question, each `StaticContract` contains a static instance of a `Registration` that is instantiated with the type passed, (`StaticContract<typename T>` and will have a `Registration<T>`):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Registration :
    public Registrants
{
public:
    Registration() {
        vectorOfFunctions->push_back(&T::foo);
    }
};
```

When the class inheriting from `StaticContract` is not a template, this works fine, but when its a template, it'll never push back an instance of its function, not to mention it doesn't even enforce its implementation.

How can I push back this function from the most derived class?

Comment: The issues you are having is due to the fact that when a template class is instantiated, only the parts of the class that are actually used needds to be instatiated by the compiler. I've seen people do similar things like this for automatic registration of classes, but I've never seen a clean variant that actually works. It usually involves having to declare some static variable of the class with the return-value of the registration function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)

Comment: No, because in that question, a normal class inherits from the template, but I have a template inheriting from a template. Neither of the templates are ever initialized, they just need their functions.