# Set member to same value in all instances of templated structure

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, member

I have the following struct:

```
template <typename T> struct avl_tree {
    T data;
    int balance;
    struct avl_tree <T> *Link[2];
    int (*comp)(T, T);
};
```

What I would like to do is to point the `comp` function pointer to a valid function at runtime, then have all instances of `struct avl_tree<T>` to be able to access this function.

```
int compare(int a, int b) {
    return ( a - b );
}
```

Is this possible to do so that I can do something like:

```
avl_tree<int> tree(new avl_tree<int>);
tree = insert(tree, 9);
std::cout << tree->comp(tree->data, 9) << '\n';//Should print 0
```

Finally got the answer to this. [Solution:](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/109880/#msg599671)

in struct avl_tree:

```
typedef int (*compare)(T, T);
static compare comp;
```

above main:

```
template <typename T> int (*avl_tree<T>::comp)(T, T);//Initialise the pointer
```

in main:

```
avl_tree<int>::comp = compare;//Set the static member function pointer to the function to use
```

In response to my previous question, here is how you can use it:

```
avl_tree<int> tree(new avl_tree<int>);
tree = insert(tree, 9);
std::cout << avl_tree<int>::comp(tree->data, 9) << '\n';//Should print 0
```

Simple :D

Comment: Make the function pointer static?

Comment: @dwarduk

I thought of doing that, but how would I actually point it to a valid function at runtime?

Comment: @dwarduk

Here is my attempt to make it static:
`typedef int (*compare)(T, T);` `static compare comp;`

Then in main:
`avl_tree<int>::compare avl_tree<int>::comp = &compare;`

However still getting compiler errors

Comment: I had the same issue; gave up after half an hour, sorry.  I am absolutely stumped now :/

Comment: Fixed it :D See my edited post

Comment: Can you make your compare function a template too, and call it with the template parameters?

Comment: Nicely done, Smac!  I missed initialising the function pointer >.<

Comment: @NeilKirk

You can, I just templated the compare function and it still works. However I have not tested with strings and such

Comment: Your compare function is more of a difference function. It won't compile with strings as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `comp` static:

```
template <typename T> struct avl_tree {
    T data;
    int balance;
    struct avl_tree <T> *Link[2];
    static int (*comp)(T, T);
};
template <typename T> int(*::comp)(<T>, <T>);
```

You can later assign it for a particular template instance with:

```
avl_tree<int>::comp = int_compare;
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819131/c-static-member-initalization-template-fun-inside) and [this outside site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/static_data_members_and_templ.htm) for more information about initialization of static members of template classes.

Comment: Can you please explain this part:
`template <typename T> int(*::comp)(<T>, <T>);` ?

Comment: This method still produces compiler issues

Comment: I may not have the syntax quite right. The examples I extrapolated from were for data members, not function members. Declaring function pointers is tricky (that's why people often typedef them).

Answer (score 1):

Im having some difficult to understand your question, but Im thinking why dont you do simply something like that:

```
template <typename T> struct avl_tree {
    T data;
    int balance;
    struct avl_tree <T> *Link[2];
    int comp(T x) { return compare(data, x);}
};
```

and make sure that your T struct or type has a conversion method to int.

Comment: Not what I am looking for but thanks for the solution. @dwarduk gave me the correct name for what I need which is to make the function pointer static, and use it the way Barmer has shown below

Answer (score 0):

Do like following

```
avl_tree<int> *tree =new avl_tree<int>;

tree->comp =compare; //Your function
std::cout << tree->comp(tree->data, 9) << '\n';
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/YteoMG)

Comment: But would this work for all instances of the class `avl_tree<T>`? i.e. I would need to do this for all instances of the class but I can't due to encapsulation of the class from the comparison function. Which is why I want to do it just once and all instances will use that declaration

Comment: @Smac89 are you saying want every instantiation of avl_tree? to use the same `compare` function?

Comment: I think he means all `avl_tree<int>` should use one comparison function, all `avl_tree<char>` should use a different one, and so on.

Comment: @RyanHaining

yes that is that I am saying
-Every instance with the same type should use the same compare

Comment: @Smac89 in that case you want Tomas Badan's solution.  Though there are more polymorphic ways to do this, such as `std::less`

Comment: @Smac89 for every unique `T` you can have separate `comp`. All child of same `T` can use same `comp`. If fact, I guess, you'll be using `comp` through `*tree`, so it will make sense to attach all childs to use same `comp`